# QTimer firing issue in QGIS(Quantum GIS)

Tags: qt, multithreading, timer, qgis

I have been involved in building a custum QGIS application in which live data is to be shown on the viewer of the application.

The IPC being used is unix message queues.

The data is to be refreshed at a specified interval say, 3 seconds.

Now the problem that i am facing is that the processing of the data which is to be shown is taking more than 3 seconds,so what i have done is that before the app starts to process data for the next update,the refresh QTimer is stopped and after the data is processed i again restart the QTimer.The app should work in such a way that after an update/refresh(during this refresh the app goes unresponsive) the user should get ample time to continue to work on the app apart from seeing the data being updated.I am able to get acceptable pauses for the user to work-- in one scenario.

But on different OS(RHEL 5.0 to RHEL 5.2) the situation is something different.The timer goes wild and continues to fire without giving any pauses b/w the successive updates thus going into an infinite loop.Handling this update data definitely takes longer than 3 sec,but for that very reason i have stopped-restarted the timer while processing..and the same logic works in one scenario while in other it doesnt.. The other fact that i have observed is that when this quick firing of the timer happens the time taken by the refreshing function to exit is very small abt 300ms so the start-stop of the timer that i have placed at the start-and-end of this function happens in that small time..so before the actual processing of the data finishes,there are 3-4 starts of the timer in queue waiting to be executed and thus the infinite looping problem gets worse from that point for every successive update.

The important thing to note here is that for the same code in one OS the refresh time is shown to be as around 4000ms(the actual processing time taken for the same amount of data) while for the other OS its 300ms.

Maybe this has something to do with newer libs on the updated OS..but I dont know how to debug it because i am not able to get any clues why its happening as such... maybe something related to pthreads has changed b/w the OSs??

So, my query is that is there any way that will assure that some processing in my app is timerised(and which is independent of the OS) without using QTimer as i think that QTimer is not a good option to achieve what i want??

What option can be there?? pthreads or Boost threads?  which one would be better if i am to use threads as an alternate??But how can i make sure atleast a 3 second gap b/w successive updates no matter how long the update processing takes?

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: other flaw that i believe is that the stop-start  command of the timer is within the execution code that resulted from the firing of that very QTimer itself
i.e when the stop-start statements for the next execution cycle are executed the QTimer is active for that very cycle under execution,any bad impacts due to this,any suggestions?Actually this refresh function is not only called due to the timer getting fired but also upon zooming/panning of the viewer,so i had to stop the data processing for the time the user zooms/pans so as to keep the app responsive,and ofcourse to keep from segfaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was trying to get an acceptable, longer-term solution, I would investigate updating your display in a separate thread.  In that thread, you could paint the display to an image, updating as often as you desire... although you might want to throttle the thread so it doesn't take all of the processing time available.  Then in the UI thread, you could read that image and draw it to screen.  That could improve your responsiveness to panning, since you could be displaying different parts of the image.  You could update the image every 3 seconds based on a timer (just redraw from the source), or you could have the other thread emit a signal whenever the new data is completely refreshed.

Comment: ...or rather, do you work in another thread - the UI *must* be updated in the *main* thread. Otherwise, this is the way to go. It sounds like what you're doing is computationally expensive - unless you can optimise it a whole load you're going to have UI freezes unless you put it on a separate thread.